# Java program not showing output

Tags: java, output

This is the coding i have come up with for a simple car rent java program. it compiles with no error but the output is not showing, so what should i do? Please help tx. I am a java beginner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class carRent
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name, address;
    double bodo,endodo, kilo;
    double days, charge;

    System.out.print("Name: ");
    name=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("State: ");
    address=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Beginning Odometer : ");
    bodo=input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("End Odometer : ");
    endodo=input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Days car used : ");
    days=input.nextDouble();


    kilo = endodo - bodo;
    System.out.printf("\nKilometer car driven  : ", + kilo ,"km");
    System.out.printf("\nNumber of days rented : ", + days);
    charge = days * 150.00 + kilo * 1.00;
    System.out.printf("\nTotal charge of rent  : ", + charge);
    } 
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%nKilometer car driven  :%f.2km", kilo);`

Comment: how can i make the output to two decimal place?

Comment: That's what `%.2f` does...Take a look at [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is short for "print format" which takes a format `String` and parameters with which they need to be formatted...

Instead you should be using something more like...

```
System.out.printf("%nKilometer car driven  : %.2fkm", kilo);
```

Which can output something like...

```
Name: test
State: Test
Beginning Odometer : 123.456
End Odometer : 789.123
Days car used : 10.25

Kilometer car driven  : 665.67km
Number of days rented : 10
Total charge of rent  : 2203.17
```

For example of the values...

```
    System.out.printf("%nKilometer car driven  : %.2fkm", kilo);
    System.out.printf("%nNumber of days rented : %.0f", days);
    charge = days * 150.00 + kilo * 1.00;
    System.out.printf("%nTotal charge of rent  : %.2f%n", charge);
```

For more details, take a look at [these examples](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html)

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `printf` correctly (since you didn't specify any place holders for the variables in the format `String`). I suggest you use `println` instead :

```
    kilo = endodo - bodo;
    System.out.println("\nKilometer car driven  : " + kilo + "km");
    System.out.println("\nNumber of days rented : " + days);
    charge = days * 150.00 + kilo * 1.00;
    System.out.println("\nTotal charge of rent  : " + charge);
```

Sample input and output :

```
Name: Eran
State: IL
Beginning Odometer : 1000
End Odometer : 2000
Days car used : 2

Kilometer car driven  : 1000.0km

Number of days rented : 2.0

Total charge of rent  : 1300.0
```

Comment: how may i set the output to two decimal places?

Comment: @user3544721 Using this method, you need to use a `NumberFormat`, using `printf`, something like `System.out.printf("%nKilometer car driven :%f.2km", kilo);`

Comment: but it displays like eg 60.000000.2 which is weird. why is that?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it should be `%0.2f` :P

Comment: like for the days i would like t display as an integer how do i convert from double to integer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to add multiple Strings on one line use:

```
System.out.print("I am an example String!");
```

If you want the String to be on its own line use:

```
System.out.println("I am an example String on my own line!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using:

```
System.out.println("Insert String Here");
```

Rather than `printf`, since you are not using placeholders .